# Adding SQLSRV 55 TS DLL to WAMP and Restarting Services but not reflecting

Tags: php, sql, pdo, wamp

I have been building an application for a client and developing in WAMP but been thrown at me that the companies guy who builds the database has been been building in MS SQL 2014 Developer so im trying to do some connection testing from the massive application ive built to a local SQL server i have setup but i cannot get PHP/Aapache (WAMP environment) to pick up PDO SQLSRV 55....

I have downloaded and extracted the [PDO Drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098/)

to `c:/wamp/bin/php/5.5.12/ext`

edited php.ini and added:

`extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll` 
`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`

restarted the services but when i view the phpinfo file i created its not loading for some reason.... any ideas?

I dont see a section in phpinfo "mssql" or anything similar.. also under PDO section only shows "PDO drivers    mysql, sqlite" does not seem to be adding mssql"

Comment: Just in case anyone asks, i have checked php.exe -i | more and checked that, its TS VC11

Comment: ive noticed in phpinfo under configure command it shows "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"

Comment: You also need to install [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434) as the php extension talks through ODBC to SQL Server

Comment: Says i already have it installed? or rather a higher version already installed? i have it loaded in the php.ini file and restart apache but doesnt load in phpinfo